# Browser behavior while trying directly add arrays and objects

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I am trying to simply add 2 different kinds of string, number, array, object and try analyze result, and understanding JS V8 engine working with them:

```html
<script>
var a = "Peter"; 
var b = "Martin"; 
var c = 5; 
var d = 10; 
var e = ["red", "green", "blue"];
var f = ["lily", "Lotus"];
var g = {name: "Peter", age: 29};
var h = {country: "USA", state: "New York", gender: "Male"}; 

console.log(a+b);
console.log(c+d);
console.log(e+f);
console.log(g+h);

var i = g+h; 
console.log(i); 
console.log(i[0]);
console.log(i[1]);
console.log(i[2]); 
</script>
```

In the code above I can understand:

Case 1: adding 2 strings will result "String".

Case 2: adding 2 numbers will add to be a number.

**My Question is:**

***Case 3***: How the hell trying add 2 arrays returns a string, that 2 merging last of 1st and 1st of last array?

***Case 4:*** How in world can I access of whatever thing that is produced by direct merging of 2 objects?

**Bonus Question:**

Also, someone said that while adding 2 objects I will get an array of 2 objects. While, alas I have added code with "i" to show you that its not the case friend. While doing so the JS V8 engine has returned a string writting in text "[object object][object object]"

Now, please tell for "**Case 4**", how to access the 2 objects of this array (as you said)?

Comment: JS is very loosely typed and some operators like `+` imply type coercion to it's operands if they are not numbers. Check [this](http://2ality.com/2013/04/quirk-implicit-conversion.html) up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of addition operator (+) is pretty well stated in [spec](https://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1).

As you can see, before returning the *sum*, both operands are get *converted* to primitive:

> 5. Let *lprim* be **ToPrimitive**(lval).
> 6. Let *rprim* be **ToPrimitive**(rval).

Now let's see what **ToPrimitive** actually returns [here](https://es5.github.io/#x9.1). Well, it returns the same input for *all* types, except for **Objects**:

> Return a default value for the Object. The default value of an object is retrieved by calling the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of the object, passing the optional hint PreferredType. The behaviour of the [[DefaultValue]] internal method is defined by this specification for all native ECMAScript objects in 8.12.8.

So, for example for **Arrays**, we get a string of its elements joined with commas:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];   // "1,2,3"
```

Because for default value it returns the result of *toString* function, if it's a primitive value.

For **Objects**, it's by default the following string: `[object Object]`.

Now getting back to **ToPrimitive**. Point 7 states that if one of the operands is a string, the other is also converted to string and the concatenation of both is returned. That's why in your case:

```
var e = ["red", "green", "blue"];
var f = ["lily", "Lotus"];
console.log(e + f);
```

1. `e` becomes `"red,green,blue"`
2. `f` becomes `"lily,Lotus"`
3. the concatenation is returned, i.e `"red,green,bluelily,Lotus"`

The same for objects. Regardless of contents, the `object.toString()` becomes `[object Object]` and the *sum* of your objects will result in `"[object Object][object Object]"`.

As you can see, in the other cases (point 8), it will try to convert operands to numbers and then return the sum of them.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't just add arrays in JavaScript, when you try to use the addition operator, JavaScript represents their values as strings and adds them together then splits with `,` and joins them back, however, you can concatenate them with `a.concat(b)`.

And for objects you can use `Object.assign({}, a, b)`

```html
<script>
var a = "Peter"; 
var b = "Martin"; 
var c = 5; 
var d = 10; 
var e = ["red", "green", "blue"];
var f = ["lily", "Lotus"];
var g = {name: "Peter", age: 29};
var h = {country: "USA", state: "New York", gender: "Male"}; 

console.log(a+b);
console.log(c+d);
console.log(e.concat(f));
console.log(Object.assign({}, g, h));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you paste your code into the browser console, that last 2 will be like this:

```
red,green,bluelily,Lotus
[object Object][object Object]
```

It looks like what it has done in 3) is render the arrays as strings (probably using the `join()` function, which by default separates them witn a comma.

In 4) it has simply returned an array of 2 objects.

There are libraries like lodash and underscore that have utilities for manipulating arrays and objects which many people use, as well as some built in functions which suffice.

Comment: #4 returns a string that concatenates the two string representations of objects.